# Are deleted files accessible if behind cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to wrap my head around how cloudfront and CDNs work.
If I have a file and the cache control header is set to 1 year and I am using amazon cloud front as my CDN.
What happens if I delete the file? Would it still be served as it is cached by the cloudfront servers? Would it be served in all locations of the world, or does it only get cached on an edge server if it has been requested once.

Example I have a file behind Amazon Cloud Front
blue.jpg with cache control headers set for 1 year

I visit the file from a location in New York

I then delete the file.

If I then visit the page which includes the file again from New York, Would the file be served as its cached?

What if someone then visits the page with the file from Moscow, Russia. Would he be able to view the file?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

CloudFront is simply a collection of caches close to your users. Each edge location operates independently.

By default, CloudFront obeys your http cache control headers. If you set your headers so a file does not expire for a year, the CloudFront will continue serving that file for a year without checking back to your origin server.

Since each edge location operates independently, in your example, New York will continue serving the file, but Moscow will the file as deleted (404). As you can imaging this could lead to different users seeing different content.

There are strategies to avoid this problem.

From the CloudFront docs (http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/#details):

> Object Versioning and Cache Invalidation
> You have two options to update your files cached at the Amazon CloudFront edge locations. You can use object versioning to manage changes to your content. To implement object versioning, you create a unique filename in your origin server for each version of your file and use the file name corresponding to the correct version in your web pages or applications. With this technique, Amazon CloudFront caches the version of the object that you want without needing to wait for an object to expire before you can serve a newer version.
>
> You can also remove copies of a file from all Amazon CloudFront edge locations at any time by calling the invalidation API. This feature removes the file from every Amazon CloudFront edge location regardless of the expiration period you set for that file on your origin server. If you need to remove multiple files at once, you may send a list of files (up to 1,000) in an XML document. The invalidation feature is designed to be used in unexpected circumstances, e.g., to correct an encoding error on a video you uploaded or an unanticipated update to your website’s CSS file. However, if you know beforehand that your files will change frequently, it is recommended that you use object versioning to manage updates to your files. This technique gives you more control over when your changes take effect and also lets you avoid potential charges for invalidating objects.